# Nginx + php fastcgi showing "No input file specified." instead of 404

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, fpm

My problem is quite simple.

When I request a .php file that doesn't exist, I see "No input file specified.", instead of the 404 page that you would expect.

I get that i am passing all requests with a .php extension to php-fpm, and i guess that php-fpm returns "No input file specified." when the file does not exist(?).
How do i fix this?

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
http {
    server {
            listen              443 ssl;
            server_name         smarthome.dk;
            ssl_certificate     /home/www/SmartHome/cert/ssl.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /home/www/SmartHome/cert/ssl.key;
            ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            keepalive_timeout   70;

            root /home/www/SmartHome/public_html;
            index index.php index.html;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /404.php?$args;
            }
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            }
    }
```

I have `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;` in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

You need to add `try_files $uri $uri/ /404.php?$args;` to `location ~\.php$`

No input file is specified because the file does not exist, and therefore is not passed. `try_files $uri $uri/ /404.php?$args;` checks that the file does actually exist, otherwise it redirects to 404.php

Comment: Accept your answer to close the query

Comment: @Dayo You have to wait 2 days, before you can accept your own answer.