# "No input file specified." error encountered instead of 404 error in NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

I am facing the same dreaded "No input file specified." message in NGINX. A brief description of what I am trying to achieve is as given below.

1. Any existing URL ending with ".php" extension should show as 404 error [working]
2. Any existing URL without ".php" extension will execute the file [working]
3. Any non-existent URL should throw 404 error [not working]. In this case the error thrown by NGINX is "No input file specified."

I have visited and tried to implement the solution located at [Nginx + php fastcgi showing "No input file specified." instead of 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381122/nginx-php-fastcgi-showing-no-input-file-specified-instead-of-404) but this did not solve my problem.

I am really not sure how to render 404 page in case of point 3.

Contents of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file is given below

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.com;
    error_page 404 /error/custom_404;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/  @missing;
    }

    location ~ (\.php$|myadmin) {
    return 404;
    }

    location @missing {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME "$document_root$uri.php";
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED "$document_root$uri.php";
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $args;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that I am just a beginner and not an expert. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location @missing` block does nothing to verify the existence of the file before passing it to `php-fpm`. Add a check for file existence:

```
location @missing {
    if (!-f $document_root$uri.php) { return 404; }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) for more, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Adding `try_files $uri.php =404;` in the missing block throws 404 error for all the requests which were earlier served. try_files is present in another block above it.

Comment: Sorry my bad, `try_files` changes the URI. Answer updated to use an `if` statement instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RichardSmith. This was what I needed.